# Maximum length of Command parameters in Windows 8 scheduler

Tags: windows-8, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have a console application that takes input command line arguments. I have to schedule this task on **Windows 8** using **Win32.TaskScheduler**. The problem is whenever my command line arguments length exceeds 450 characters, i get a warning like this :

```
Task registered task "TaskName" , but not all specified triggers will start the task. User Action: Ensure all the task triggers are valid as configured. Additional Data: Error Value: 2147944183.
```

And the task does not run eventually at the run time.
Is there any limit on command line arguments' length?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with scheduled tasks and command line arguments that exceeded 260 characters. We got the same useless error that you did.

Eventually we had to change the command line arguments so they were smaller (length of file paths in argument list)

We had this issue on Windows Server 2012 R2 64 bit, I'm not sure if the bitness has anything to do with it...